# HTML Image and Text

Tags: html, css

Code:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row py-4">
  <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage">
    <img src="https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/google.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block" style="width:512px;height:640px; float:right" alt="Google">
    <b><h3> Google </h3></b>
    <p> Google Play Store </p>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage">
    <img src="https://images.livemint.com/img/2019/09/12/600x338/TA_-_2019-09-12T171956.640_1568289017643.png" class="img-fluid d-block" style="width:512px;height:640px; float:left" alt="Gmail">
    <b> <h3> Google Gmail </h3> </b>
    <p> Gmail </p> <br>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Image(1) :

[image]

With Float Left and Right(2):

[image]

> Problem: when i
>    add `float:left` and `float:right`, the text will changed position.
>   (wanted the text and link below the image
>
> What i wanted: I want both image placement is like Image(2) + Text and
>   Link is below the image

Comment: <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage" >

Here you can use text-left or text right instead of text-center for your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `float`, you have to use `clear:<right|left|both` or `clearfix` class if you use `bootstrap` after those elements.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row py-4">
  <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage">
    <img src="https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/google.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block" style="width:512px;height:640px; float:right" alt="Google">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <b><h3> Google </h3></b>
    <p> Google Play Store </p>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage">
    <img src="https://images.livemint.com/img/2019/09/12/600x338/TA_-_2019-09-12T171956.640_1568289017643.png" class="img-fluid d-block" style="width:512px;height:640px; float:left" alt="Gmail">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <b> <h3> Google Gmail </h3> </b>
    <p> Gmail </p> <br>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I don't recommend, you have to deal with problems later as well.

**Better solution** is to use `flexbox`, `display: flex` for `css` or class `d-flex` for boostrap for container. It will have flexible opportunities for manage layout.

**UPDATE for css**

```css
.left-image-div-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.right-image-div-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.image-div-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row py-4">
  <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage left-image-div-container">
    <div class="image-div-wrapper">
      <img src="https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/google.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block" style="width:512px;height:640px;" alt="Google">
      <b><h3> Google </h3></b>
      <p> Google Play Store </p>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage right-image-div-container">
    <div class="image-div-wrapper">
      <img src="https://images.livemint.com/img/2019/09/12/600x338/TA_-_2019-09-12T171956.640_1568289017643.png" class="img-fluid d-block" style="width:512px;height:640px;" alt="Gmail">
      <b> <h3> Google Gmail </h3> </b>
      <p> Gmail </p> <br>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Solution for bootstrap**

Wrap your images and link with `divs` with `d-flex flex-column align-items-center` classes. Remove `float` from images `styles`. Add to `col` `divs` `d-flex` class and `justify-content-end` for the first one, and `justify-content-start` for the second.

Look example in snippet.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row py-4">
  <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage d-flex justify-content-end">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <img src="https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/google.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block" style="width:512px;height:640px;" alt="Google">
      <b><h3> Google </h3></b>
      <p> Google Play Store </p>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage d-flex justify-content-start">
    <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
      <img src="https://images.livemint.com/img/2019/09/12/600x338/TA_-_2019-09-12T171956.640_1568289017643.png" class="img-fluid d-block" style="width:512px;height:640px;" alt="Gmail">
      <b> <h3> Google Gmail </h3> </b>
      <p> Gmail </p> <br>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Everything work fines , i wondered that do you have the "standalone" CSS ? as do not want to link external css (crashing with my current website)

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

First remove the **`float:left`** and **`float:right`** from both images

And then you have to just add this CSS code.

```
.leftimage>img{
  display: block;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: still the same ( need the image like in image 2 (center with text) but if i add float , the text with misplacement )

Comment: please check here did you not wanna like that [link](https://codepen.io/Bilawal_12597/pen/dyoPLoo)

Answer (score 0):

use this code this will solve your problem,the problem was **you have placed the float option in image not the div**, if not work please let me know . thank you. heres the codepen link

> **https://codepen.io/salmanaabir/pen/VwLLZRG**

```
<div class="row py-4">
<div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage" style="float:left;">
    <img src="https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/google.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block" style="height:640px;text-align:center;"  alt="Google">
    <b><h3> Google </h3></b>
    <p> Google Play Store </p>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
</div>
<div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6 text-center leftimage" style="float:right;">
    <img src="https://images.livemint.com/img/2019/09/12/600x338/TA_-_2019-09-12T171956.640_1568289017643.png" class="img-fluid d-block" style="height:640px;text-align:center;"  alt="Gmail">
        <b> <h3> Google Gmail </h3> </b>
    <p> Gmail </p> <br>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row py-4">
    <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6" >
        <img src="https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/google.jpeg" class="img-fluid d-block" style="width:512px;height:640px;"  alt="Google">
<div class="caption">
        <b><h3> Google </h3></b>
        <p> Google Play Store </p>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 mb-3 col-md-6">
        <img src="https://images.livemint.com/img/2019/09/12/600x338/TA_-_2019-09-12T171956.640_1568289017643.png" class="img-fluid d-block" style="width:512px;height:640px; float:left"  alt="Gmail">
<div class="caption">
            <b> <h3> Google Gmail </h3> </b>
        <p> Gmail </p> <br>
        <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Link</a>
</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try adding align = "bottom" to the image tag or add enough 
 before the text string until it appears below the image.